# How to travel without visa by having 2 citizenships?

Tags: passports, international-travel

Disclaimer: This question is only theoretical to me, but could be reality for other people I guess. I will write the question AS IF I would be the person wanting to travel in those conditions.

So, I "am" the citizen of two countries. People from these countries must have a prior visa in their passports before traveling to the other country.

But since I am a citizen of both countries, I should not need a visa at all, just to use the proper passport in the proper place, right?

Well, I have this idea in my mind that in the airports (and maybe other places) I might encounter some issues. Since the ticket is round-trip, and since the tickets are linked to one of the passports, how can I travel without trouble?

Ideally, I do not want to show both passports, and I do not want to buy two independent tickets, each linked to one of the passports.

Comment: With the huge number of countries from which you can have a passport, combined with the huge number of countries from which you can have a visa and the huge number of options of combinations makes that this question can not be answered as a theoretical what if question.

Comment: I have a related question (also hypothetical, however - it is specific to 3 countries - Australia AUS, India IND, Nepal NEP). So, _what if_ person X has AUS passport (naturalized/acquired), but originally IND citizen (and holds expired IND passport - technically, needs to be surrendered) and stuck in IND (without valid visa). IND - NEP travel possible without passport, visa for IND citizen. So, if they travel by-road to NEP using IND documents (DL, etc), can they then request NEP for entry-stamp on AUS passport (they won't have IND exit-stamp on AUS passport)? Should I post new question?

Comment: @infrequent-traveller OCIs don't need a visa to IND to the best of my knowledge and cat stay there for as long as they want. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @littleadv - The hypothetical situation is that the person travelled from AUS to IND using IND passport (which needs to be surrendered; however, if used for travel there is a penalty payable at the time of surrender to the IND Consulate). The comment indicates: _holds expired IND passport - technically, needs to be surrendered_ + _ stuck in IND (without valid visa)_ --> please consider this statement  as: "without valid visa + without valid OCI".

Comment: @infrequent-traveller this seems like a different question entirely from the OPs, and probably relates to how India handles use of its passport by those who are not citizens. Probably not very favorably to the person in this scenario, but then again - he clearly broke a law he very well knew of.

Comment: @littleadv, Will probably post a separate question then. It has been brought to my attention that: IND consulate has very clear description / instruction on what one needs to do if one has traveled using their IND passport *after* acquiring citizenship elsewhere. This involves paying a penalty based on how often they traveled, whether they renewed their IND passport, etc. This penalty needs to be paid via VFS when the IND passport/s is/are surrendered.

Comment: @infrequent-traveller: your question is definitely different, because you mentioned expired passport. In my (theoretical) question, all documents are OK. So yes, it would be better to post a new question to get a better answer for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly common actually and in fact is *often* the only way allowed.
*Generally*, citizens of a country are not allowed to apply for a visa to their own country. Although can apply as a citizen of the other country, visa forms tend to ask a lot of question covering your background, including whether you are a citizen of another country. Plus, it is common for countries to specify that citizens of their own country must use the matching passport when entering or exiting.

The typical procedure is to show passports as follow when going from your origin to your destination:

- Origin Check-In: Passport of your destination country
- Origin Exit Immigration: Passport of your origin country (Some countries do not have exit immigration)
- Outgoing Transit Check-In: Passport of your destination country (If applicable)
- Destination Arrival Immigration: Passport of the destination country

And as follows when returning from your destination to the origin:

- Destination Check-In: Passport of your origin country
- Destination Exit Immigration:  Passport of the destination country
- Return Transit Check-In: Passport of your origin country
- Origin Arrival Immigration: Passport of your origin country

Given all possible combination of countries, it is likely that there are some exceptions to the above procedure but that would require a more specific question. Also, it is possible to encounter some complications such as when your travel documents have different names and one way or the other, the name on the passport does not match the ticket on the name. For small differences (such as accented characters missing accents on one or a truncated name), they will *often* be understood but more significant differences will be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The last point, about different names, is very interesting. I did not take into consideraion that it can happen.